# "Compare with" or "Comparing with" on a title

Tags: headlinese

I have a title which I am going to compare my approach with another approach namely X and highlight the advantages of my approach in the section.

Which of the following is correct for the title?

> Compare with X
>
> Comparing with X

Comment: They are both correct. As are *compares with X* and *compared with X*. You will need to be more specific.

Comment: For a title it is more likely to be: **Comparisons with X** but without more information it's hard, as Jason remarks, to be helpful.

Comment: @RonaldSole Thanks. This is all the things I would like to write in a title with no more words.

Comment: If that's the entire title, then it would almost certainly have to be **Comparisons with X**.  But it's a confusing title and almost certainly not how a native English speaker would write it, because usually you're comparing two things, not just one.